# How do I prevent the control box getting focus when I press Alt?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I want the user to be able to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to apply certain modifications to mouse actions. Like instead of scrolling vertically when using the mouse wheel, the view would scroll horizontally (while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is being held).

This works great, but after releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, my control no longer has focus. When I press <kbd>Space</kbd>, I can see why. The window menu got the focus because I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I learned kbd tag today.

Comment: @rageit: It's very popular on [su] ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing this isn't so easy, you need to prevent the WM_SYSKEYDOWN message from reaching the default window procedure.  That's only practical by filtering it before it reaches the control with the focus.  That's possible by having your form implement the IMessageFilter interface.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        // Trap WM_SYSKEYUPDOWN message for the ALT key
        if ((Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() == Keys.Menu) {
            if (m.Msg == 0x104) { AltKeyPressed = true; return true; }
            if (m.Msg == 0x105) { AltKeyPressed = false; return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private bool AltKeyPressed;
}
```

Beware of the many side effects, it stops a menu behaving normally and shortcut keystrokes that use Alt are not going to work anymore.  Do consider using Ctrl or Shift instead.

Comment: Awesome. This works like a charm. I can even implement this directly in the `Control` where I want this behavior. I was trying to emulate the behavior of Photoshop in this code (where Alt+Wheel scales the canvas), which is why I didn't go for Ctrl or Shift. However, this being a `Control` that requires this feature, I'm concerned about possible side effects due to portability. I'll see how I'll handle it :)

Answer (score 0):

After the Alt gesture has been released, programmatically force your control to have focus by calling Control.Focus().

Why is this hack acceptable? Because this behavior is restricted to instances when your control has focus and the gesture is successfully processed.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to register on the keyboard event and flag the event as handled,
i dont mean KeyPressed or even KeyDown...
i mean OnPreviewKeyDown  (dont remmember the exact name but googling will do)

Comment: yes, i used it once when  i was building a Grid Control...
when you flag the event as handled.

Comment: Hans showen a more advanced method for disregarding this KeyDown message, by interveening in the Message loop.

Comment: Given the number of 'side effects' ('many', as stated) I would pause before calling it more advanced.